# Terminal Issue in VS Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

How are you doing? I hope you're doing well :) I ran into some complications while reinstalling & using VS Code
I was trying to get the face_recognition library for Python to run on there, it did not work (around mid April, May), so I tried it again, and it worked
So I tried to change the theme, and ran into the following error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i23A.jpg

If you could help me out with this error I'd be grateful, thank you and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a coma after 1 in line 6

[image: Where you should enter a coma]

Comment: But I'd like to know, what mistake I did, and how can I avoid it in the future. And should I ignore the "This is deprecated, the new recommended..." comment appearing when I open the json file?

Comment: @SyedMasroorHussain You can ignore the "deprecated" warning but it means that there is another way to configure now and that way will not be used in the future.